# Using figtext in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do you use the `figtext` function in Python?

I tried `help(figtext)` but the instructions returned were too vague.

I am trying to add the variance and mode to a graph of data.

I tried simply doing

```
figtext(median,mode)
```

but that wasn't right.

Comment: Please add a specific question, state what you have done, what error you are receiving, what Google says, and more.  Then someone may be able to help you.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. As I said I am trying to add the median and the mode to a graph of the data set. Google doesn't say much about the specific function.

I can't really say a specific error as I don't know how to use the function.

Answer (score 4):

According to help and [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figtext):

```
figtext(*args, **kwargs)
    Call signature::

      text(x, y, s, fontdict=None, **kwargs)

    Add text to figure at location *x*, *y* (relative 0-1
    coords). See :func:`~matplotlib.pyplot.text` for the meaning
    of the other arguments.
```

thus

```
figtext(.3,.5,str(median))
figtext(.4,.5,str(mean))
```

will add the text to the middle of the figure.  Tweak the values of `x` and `y` values to put the text where you want.   You will likely also want to use formatting to not get lots of meaningless numbers (`'%.02f'%mean`).

Comment: @user1778543 if this answer solved your problem you should accept it so that others know that your problem has been solved. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask